# Special characters throwing error in ITextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, pdfptable

ITextSharp is used in my application for viewing the data from the database in a pdf format.

```
 Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
 document.Open();

 PdfPTable detail = GetTable(4, 500f, 0);
 foreach (var Stage in stageDetails)
   {
      detail.AddCell(GetCellDetails(Stage.Key,string.Empty, 4, 0, 0));                            
      detail.AddCell(GetCellDetails(string.Empty,Stage.Value, 4, 0, 0, 0f, 1, 0, 8, 0, 1));
   }                    
 document.Add(detail);
```

GetCellDetails is another method for generating the css style

```
 public static PdfPCell GetCellDetails(string Topic, string value, int Colspan, int HorizontalAlignment, int main = 1, float Length = 0f, int IsHeight = 0, int IsBorder = 0, int PaddingBottom = 8, int PaddingTop = 0, int IsHTML = 0)
    {
        var phrase = new Phrase();
        var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD);
        var SubtitleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD);
        var SubAnsFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL);
        if (main == 1)
        {
            phrase.Add(new Chunk(Topic, titleFont));
        }
        else
        {
            if (Topic != string.Empty && value != string.Empty)
            {
                phrase.Add(new Chunk(Topic, SubtitleFont));
                phrase.Add(new Chunk(value, SubAnsFont));
            }
            else if (Topic != string.Empty)
            {
                phrase.Add(new Chunk(Topic, SubtitleFont));
            }
            else if (value != string.Empty)
            {
                phrase.Add(new Chunk(value, SubAnsFont));
            }
        }
        Paragraph Paragraph = new Paragraph(phrase);
        if (main == 2 || main == 3 || main == 4)
        {
            if (Length >= 100f)
            {
                LineSeparator LineSeparator = new LineSeparator((main == 4) ? 3.5f : (main == 2) ? 1.5f : 0.2f, Length, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, -1);
                Paragraph.Add(LineSeparator);
            }
            else
            {
                LineSeparator LineSeparator = new LineSeparator(1f, Length, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, -1);
                Paragraph.Add(LineSeparator);
            }
        }
        PdfPCell Cell = new PdfPCell(Paragraph);
        if (IsHTML == 1)
        {
            Cell = new PdfPCell();
            StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
            css.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.DIV, HtmlTags.FONTSIZE, "8");
            css.LoadStyle("tHeader", "size", "15ptx");
            css.LoadStyle("rows", "color", "red");
            css.LoadStyle("left", "width", "auto");
            css.LoadStyle("left", "float", "left");

            css.LoadStyle("right", "width", "auto");
            css.LoadStyle("right", "float", "right");
            css.LoadStyle("right", "border", "solid 1px blue");
            css.LoadStyle("lbl", "font-weight", "700");
            css.LoadStyle("content", "size", "15ptx");
            string[] spilt = { "<hr/>", "<hr />" };
            foreach (string ab in spilt)
            {
                value = value.Replace(ab, "<table border='1' width=auto cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>");
            }
            var objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(value), css);
            for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; ++k)
            {
                Cell.AddElement((IElement)objects[k]);
            }
        }
        if (IsHeight == 1)
        {
            Cell.MinimumHeight = 25f;
        }
        Cell.BorderWidthBottom = (IsBorder == 4) || (IsBorder == 6) || (IsBorder == 5) || (IsBorder == 1) || (IsBorder == 8) || (IsBorder == 9) || (IsBorder == 7) ? 1 : 0;
        Cell.BorderWidthRight = (IsBorder == 3) || (IsBorder == 6) || (IsBorder == 1) || (IsBorder == 9) ? 1 : 0;
        Cell.BorderWidthLeft = (IsBorder == 2) || (IsBorder == 4) || (IsBorder == 1) || (IsBorder == 8) ? 1 : 0;
        Cell.BorderWidthTop = (IsBorder == 1) ? 1 : 0;
        Cell.Colspan = Colspan;
        if (PaddingTop == 1)
        {
            Cell.PaddingTop = 8;
        }
        Cell.PaddingBottom = PaddingBottom;
        Cell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment;
        return Cell;
    }
```

The problem is with the special characters, it shows some error like The table width must be greater than zero.How can I encode and decode using this piece of code?What is the solution for this issue?

Comment: Your question is wrong. The error message `The table width must be greater than zero` means that there's an error in your HTML causing iText to create a table with a width of 0. Adding a table with a width of 0 doesn't make sense. Also: you are using `HTMLWorker`. That's an obsolete class **that should no longer be used**, see [the introduction of the iText 7 + pdfHTML tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) for more info. Please throw away all your code, and start anew with a more recent version of iText.

Comment: But the error is like that.I tried without using special characters , it is working fine.When my data contains special characters , it shows error

Comment: Yes, `HTMLWorker` is as unreliable as that. If it rains, it works; if the sun shines, it kind of works, but as soon as the moon rises, it fails. Well, not exactly, but I hope this helps you get the point that `HTMLWorker` **should no longer be used!** Trust me, I know, I'm the original developer of iText.

Comment: But I cant throw away all my code,and start a new.Can I do something using this code?It will be helpful to me

Comment: It depends on how much time you want to spend. Throwing away the code and starting anew will take less time than looking at the open source code and fixing something that has been broken for many years.

Comment: Are you sure this will fix special character issue?if yes,i will start working on it.But the fact is that for all other scenarios HTMLworker is working fine

Comment: Well, the advantage of pdfHTML is that special characters are supported out-of-the-box, see [How to render certain HTML entities (such as arrows) to PDF?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/how-render-certain-html-entities-such-arrows-pdf) and that you don't have to use a `StyleSheet` object, but you can just use [CSS](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-2-defining-styles-css). So your new code will be minimal.